# comparing two columns from two mysql tables to find distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have two table as

Employee table

```
id  username    status
1   user1       retire
2   user2       retire
3   user3       working
4   user4       working
5   user5       working
6   user6       working
7   user7       retire
```

Report Table

```
id  username    task    date
1   user3       task1   2018-02-15
2   user3       task2   2018-02-15
3   user3       task3   2018-02-15
4   user4       task1   2018-02-15
5   user4       task2   2018-02-15
6   user4       task3   2018-02-15
7   user4       task1   2018-02-16
8   user5       task1   2018-02-16
9   user5       task2   2018-02-16
10  user5       task3   2018-02-16
11  user5       task4   2018-02-16
12  user3       task2   2018-02-16
13  user3       task3   2018-02-16
```

What I have to do is, first select username from employee table those have status working and compare them with username from report table for particular date. I used left outer join for the same, it gave me result but not exactly what I intended, my query for outer join is

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.username FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN report     
ON employee.username = report.username WHERE report.username IS null And     
employee.status = 'working'
```

I want to add further condition of dates from report table, but I am not able to get it, can someone suggest me how can I get the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Distinct(employee.username) FROM employee where employee.status = 'working' 
and employee.username not in (SELECT report.username from report where 
report.date = 'YourDate')
```

Comment: @Shahbaz Khan Try this query you will get required Output what your want

Comment: thank you for your response, your answer solved my problem. I would accept this as answer, kindly would you say what these types of queries are called

Comment: A Query which contains Sub Queries

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

```
Select * from ReportTable 
where taskDate between @minValue and @maxValue
and userName in (select username from Employee where status = 'working')
```

Comment: I wanted to use this type of query only, but when i tried i was not able to get syntax properly, so i switched for joins, I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be incomplete, still i try to answer as far as i understand this. It looks you try to add the date filter in the where clause but you had used REPORT TABLE "LEFT OUTER JOIN" with EMPLOYEE TABLE. It is good practice not to use where clause conditions to filter the records from LEFT OUTER JOINed Table, instead you can use that condition in ON clause (where do you use the LEFT OUTER JOIN)

Regards,

Ananda Kumar J.

Comment: actually, I want to know employees not present in report table for particular date ,from total employees  of employee table, but since employee table is having employees with status 'working' and 'retire' so i want to know , from all working employees from employee table, who is not present in report table for a perticular date.

Comment: I hope it may explain my query

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` wrong
2. Mention the relationship between the tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.username FROM report 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.username = report.username
WHERE report.username IS null And employee.status = 'working'
and taskDate between @minValue and @maxValue
```

Comment: I want only for one date , not for between two dates, when i was using second AND for date it was giving syntax error

Comment: the syntax error was in earlier attempts.. for this query , given by @ksl123, in result, it is returning o rows

Comment: post your result set and query